# An error ocurred while starting the kernel (connected with tornado)

Tags: python, kernel, tornado

I just installed tensorflow framework and now I can't run my code in spyder IDE. It writes

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.
```

from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp

Nothing works! Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I met this too. and I found it's caused by the same error [here](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/issues/16):

and I resolve it by:

```
conda install nomkl
```